# skip or delete column from excel using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The query is executed and all data i get in once. I don't want to show some of the column(s) of table in excel. I'm using POI. Now it's better to give column name instead of column number to delete/skip that column. In app.xml i specified two property and trying to add condition but not getting how to to add. I have 5 sheets in my file do i have to mention property tag to every sheet. The problem is i'm not able to delete the column from sheet which i've mentioned in app.xml

`<property key="sheet.name" value="abc">
<property key="column.name" value="chart,axis">`

```
XSSFSheet sheet;
XSSFFont font = setFont(workBook.createFont(), bold, italic);
CellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
try {
        sheet = workBook.createSheet(sheetName);
        sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
        if (props.containsKey("sheet.name")) {
          sheetName = props.getProperty("sheet.name");
        }
        if (props.containsKey("colName.name")) {
          colName = props.getProperty("sheet.name");
          colName =  Arrays.asList( colName.split(","));
        }
        XSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

        for (i = 0; i < headerData.size(); i++) {

            cellStyle = setAlign(cellStyle);
            cellStyle.setFont(font);
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.valueOf(color).getIndex());
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

            cellStyle = addCellBorder(cellStyle);

            Cell cel = currentRow.createCell(cell++);
            cel.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            cel.setCellValue(camelCase(headerData.get(i)));
        }

        for (Object[] resultArray : resultList) {
            currentRow = sheet.createRow(++rowNum);
            cell = colNum;

            for (i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
                sheet.setColumnWidth(cell, 6500);
                if (resultArray[i] != null) {

                    CellStyle cs = addCellBorder(workBook.createCellStyle());
                    cs.setWrapText(true);
                    cs = setAlign(cs);

                    Cell cel = currentRow.createCell(cell++);
                    cel.setCellStyle(cs);

                    if (resultArray[i] instanceof Integer) {
                        cel.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(resultArray[i].toString()));
                    } else if (resultArray[i] instanceof Long) {
                        cel.setCellValue(Long.parseLong(resultArray[i].toString()));
                    } else if (resultArray[i] instanceof Float) {
                        cel.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(resultArray[i].toString()));
                    } else if (resultArray[i] instanceof Double) {
                        cel.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(resultArray[i].toString()));
                    } else {
                        cel.setCellValue(resultArray[i].toString());
                    }
                } else {

                    CellStyle cs = addCellBorder(workBook.createCellStyle());
                    Cell cel = currentRow.createCell(cell++);
                    cel.setCellValue(""); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    cel.setCellStyle(cs);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem/question?

Comment: The problem is i'm not able to delete the column from sheet which i've mentioned in app.xml

Comment: So you have a workbook with lets say 5 columns. In 2 if the columns, the first row contains the 2 values you specified in your .xml file right? And you want to delete these 2 columns at the end?

Comment: More like in property tag of app.xml if i specify column name(s) for that particular sheet name that column should get deleted from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the property as:

`<property key="skip.sheetname" value="column name(s) to delete" />
<property key="skip.sheetname" value="column name(s) to delete" />`

and then Try this:

```
if (props.containsKey("skip." + getSheetName())) {
     colName = props.getProperty("skip." + getSheetName());
     newList = Arrays.asList(colName.split(","));

     for (String skipHeader : newList) {
            Boolean flag = true;
            for (i = 0; i < headerData.size() && flag; i++) {
                if (headerData.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(skipHeader)) {
                    headerData.set(i, "qwe");
                    flag = false;
                    skipColIndex.add(i);
                }

            }
    }
}
```